# Redmine on Apache2 with Passenger issue

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, redmine

I installed Redmine and run it in Apache2 with the Passenger module.
Apache2 boots, Passenger module gets loaded and the Redmine welcome page is shown, however when trying to login or navigate to other parts of the Redmine site, the browser keeps loading and loading and loading forever, although the Redmine production.log indicates redirects and HTTP 200 codes in the header, so everything seems to work correctly according to the log.
I tested in various browsers.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

I will add apache configuration and some relevant log snippets from both apache and redmine hereafter.

Apache2 Redmine configuration:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www  

<Directory /var/www/redmine>
       RailsEnv production
       AllowOverride all
       RailsBaseURI /redmine
       PassengerResolveSymLinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

Apache2 error log after booting Apache:

```
[Wed Feb 09 19:59:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.2 DAV/2 SVN/1.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Redmine production log after logging in:

```
 Logfile created on Wed Feb 09 20:01:40 +0100 2011

 Processing WelcomeController#index (for 192.168.1.55 at 2011-02-09 20:01:48) [GET]
 Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"welcome"}
 Rendering template within layouts/base
 Rendering welcome/index
 Completed in 220ms (View: 96, DB: 16) | 200 OK [http://sirius/redmine]


 Processing AccountController#login (for 192.168.1.55 at 2011-02-09 20:03:17) [GET]
 Parameters: {"action"=>"login", "controller"=>"account"}
 Rendering template within layouts/base
 Rendering account/login
 Completed in 85ms (View: 63, DB: 1) | 200 OK [http://sirius/redmine/login]


 Processing AccountController#login (for 192.168.1.55 at 2011-02-09 20:03:20) [POST]
 Parameters: {"back_url"=>"http%3A%2F%2Fsirius%2Fredmine", "action"=>"login", "authenticity_token"=>"cEMUZHhRKJU8w3p6d+xQQhJTk4/pnnzUdg5g5fwhxDU=", "username"=>"admin", "controller"=>"account", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"Login \302\273"}
 Redirected to http://sirius/redmine
 Completed in 37ms (DB: 6) | 302 Found [http://sirius/redmine/login]


 Processing WelcomeController#index (for 192.168.1.55 at 2011-02-09 20:03:20) [GET]
 Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"welcome"}
 Rendering template within layouts/base
 Rendering welcome/index
 Completed in 100ms (View: 77, DB: 6) | 200 OK [http://sirius/redmine]
```

Apache2 error log afterwards:

> [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(247)] ModPagespeed OutputFilter called for request /redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(272)] unparsed=/redmine/login, absolute_url=http://sirius/redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: HtmlParse::StartParse
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(299)] Request headers:\nHTTP/1.1 0 Internal Server Error\r\nHost: sirius\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nKeep-Alive: 115\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: http://sirius/redmine\r\nCookie: _redmine_session=BAh7BjoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmVlMzFiMDc4MWQxZDU5ZTI5MTk2NjU0NGY3MzJmYzQ%3D--ea4b7adbc35551051632b5544faaad138ae08d90\r\n\r\n
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(302)] request->filename=/var/www/redmine/login, uri=/redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(319)] ModPagespeed Response headers:\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nStatus: 200\r\nX-Mod-Pagespeed: 0.9.0.0-128\r\n\r\n
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 2157us: HtmlParse::Flush
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 2272us: HtmlParse::CoalesceAdjacentCharactersNodes
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 2342us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:AddHead
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 2407us: HtmlParse::SanityCheck
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 2504us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CssCombine
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [warn] [0209/200317:WARNING:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(32)] Failed to create or read input resource /redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [warn] [0209/200317:WARNING:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(32)] Failed to create or read input resource /redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 3642us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CssFilter
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] http://sirius/redmine/login:9: Failed to load resource http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] http://sirius/redmine/login:17: Failed to load resource http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Failed to load resource http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 4863us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:Javascript
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:11: Found script with src /redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:12: Found script with src /redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:13: Found script with src /redmine/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:14: Found script with src /redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:15: Found script with src /redmine/javascripts/application.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/application.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 8389us: HtmlParse::SanityCheck
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 8588us: HtmlParse::CoalesceAdjacentCharactersNodes
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 8701us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:InlineCss
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: 8701us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:InlineCss
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 9199us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:InlineJs
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] Creating connectionhttp://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connectionhttp://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/application.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/application.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 11398us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:ImgRewrite
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 11506us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CacheExtender
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/prototype.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/effects.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/controls.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/javascripts/application.js?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/javascripts/application.js?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(29)] http://sirius/redmine/login: Couldn't fetch resource /redmine/stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1296181549 to rewrite.
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 14401us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:HtmlWriter
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [notice] [0209/200317:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 15218us: HtmlParse::FinishParse
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:17 2011] [error] [0209/200317:ERROR:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(54)] net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc:506: Creating connection
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [warn] [client 192.168.1.55] Not GET request: 2., referer: http://sirius/redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(247)] ModPagespeed OutputFilter called for request /redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(272)] unparsed=/redmine/login, absolute_url=http://sirius/redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: HtmlParse::StartParse
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(299)] Request headers:\nHTTP/1.1 0 Internal Server Error\r\nHost: sirius\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nKeep-Alive: 115\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: http://sirius/redmine/login\r\nCookie: _redmine_session=BAh7BzoPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNmVlMzFiMDc4MWQxZDU5ZTI5MTk2NjU0NGY3MzJmYzQ6EF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjFjRU1VWkhoUktKVTh3M3A2ZCt4UVFoSlRrNC9wbm56VWRnNWc1ZndoeERVPQ%3D%3D--8b195ac3cab88b5a1f408e3f18aaddc70782140e\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 165\r\n\r\n
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(302)] request->filename=/var/www/redmine/login, uri=/redmine/login
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(319)] ModPagespeed Response headers:\nHTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nLocation: http://sirius/redmine\r\nStatus: 302\r\nX-Mod-Pagespeed: 0.9.0.0-128\r\n\r\n
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 604us: HtmlParse::Flush
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 697us: HtmlParse::CoalesceAdjacentCharactersNodes
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 758us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:AddHead
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 813us: HtmlParse::SanityCheck
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 912us: HtmlParse::CoalesceAdjacentCharactersNodes
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 965us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CssCombine
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1020us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CssFilter
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1073us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:Javascript
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1125us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:InlineCss
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1179us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:InlineJs
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1233us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:ImgRewrite
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1285us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CacheExtender
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1338us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:HtmlWriter
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine/login:1: 1415us: HtmlParse::FinishParse
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(247)] ModPagespeed OutputFilter called for request /redmine
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(272)] unparsed=/redmine, absolute_url=http://sirius/redmine
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine:1: HtmlParse::StartParse
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(299)] Request headers:\nHTTP/1.1 0 Internal Server Error\r\nHost: sirius\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\nKeep-Alive: 115\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: http://sirius/redmine/login\r\nCookie: _redmine_session=BAh7BzoMdXNlcl9pZGkGOg9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiVlYjNmYTY5NmZjNzMwYTdhMjA5ZDJmZmM4MTM0MzcyMw%3D%3D--57a4931aae681664d2a6ff6c039ac84b6ebc9e55\r\nIf-None-Match: "76628aff953f11fbdefb77ce3d575718"\r\n\r\n
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(302)] request->filename=/var/www/redmine, uri=/redmine
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/mod_instaweb.cc(319)] ModPagespeed Response headers:\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nStatus: 200\r\nX-Mod-Pagespeed: 0.9.0.0-128\r\n\r\n
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine:1: 1870us: HtmlParse::Flush
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine:1: 1973us: HtmlParse::CoalesceAdjacentCharactersNodes
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine:1: 2040us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:AddHead
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine:1: 2101us: HtmlParse::SanityCheck
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/util/google_message_handler.cc(48)] http://sirius/redmine:1: 2231us: HtmlParse::ApplyFilter:CssCombine
>   [Wed Feb 09 20:03:20 2011] [notice] [0209/200320:INFO:net/instaweb/apache/serf_url_async_fetcher.cc(632)] Initiating async fetch for http://sirius/redmine/stylesheets/application.css?1296181549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem boiled down to me screwing up host resolving on my machine by fiddling with dnsmasq and dns in general weeks ago...